# Images look different on web server

Tags: html, css, image

I've just realised that on my website, the images look a lot different to what they do on localhost. I'm not sure why, it's baffled me.

Localhost preview: http://d.pr/i/6og 
Server preview: http://d.pr/i/OWKx

Localhost gradients: http://d.pr/i/C5el 
Server gradients: http://d.pr/i/5pGi

Localhost search bar: http://d.pr/i/YL2X
Server search bar: http://d.pr/i/dTCZ

As you can see they're a lot different. I've literally no idea why, I'm wondering if anybody has had the same problem before?

My website: http://wpvault.com/kahlam/

I don't think there's anything in the CSS that could possibly do this? It's strange, quite stuck with this one. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Browser:** Google Chrome

Comment: Sorry forgot to add my browser. I'm actually using Chrome.

Comment: When you saved the files, did u use anti-aliasing?

Comment: Didn't use anti-aliasing no, but surely if I did it wouldn't matter due to the fact that these images are working fine locally?

Comment: Live site looks fine here in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange issue but I have all the images back to normal. It seems when I was uploading them from a 2mb connection it was just uploading them into really rubbish quality images. I got home and uploaded them via my 50mb connection and all was fine - all the images are now back to normal. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is color management in browsers. This isn't a fault with your images at all.

[Here](http://insig.ht/2009/11/why-photos-look-bad-in-firefox-3-5/) is the article that I read.

Here is some excerpts from the article in question:

> This specific  issue exists because there are two types of ICC profiles, V2 and V4 (all you need to know is that V4 profiles are more accurate; refer to this International Colour Consortium document for the technical specifics).
>   The trouble is:
>
> Firefox 3.0 and Safari understand ICC V2 and V4 profiles.
>
> Firefox 3.5 introduced a new colour management system which no longer understands ICC V4 profiles (great job guys).
>
> Internet Explorer 8 and Google Chrome don’t understand colour profiles at all!

**Edit**

I also found this [link](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/firefox-blurry-images.html) to blurry images in firefox, this could be related to other browsers as well.

> I recently faced a weird issue with Firefox. All the images on my blog were rather blurry as if they were wrongly scaled. So I tried with a new Firefox profile and it worked fine. So there must have been some setting or some add-on that is part of the current user profile that is causing this. I removed all the extensions and add-ons to no avail. Just moments ago, I found the solution on the Blitz Research forum. **It turns out to be an issue related to the zoom level for a given website, which Firefox 3.0 remembers. By clicking Ctrl + 0, you reset to the no zoom.**

Comment: Hmm.. I don't understand why it's working fine locally though? All the images work fine locally, but as soon as they're uploaded they look blurry.

Comment: @Xiy Good point, Im going to go and have a search for more info now.

Comment: @Xiy Updated, let me know if it didnt help

Comment: Still no luck :( - Will keep Google'ing as well. Very strange issue.